# How can I found out where the default colors are defined for TableSection?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to learn more about the Xamarin source. In particular I would like to find out what the background color of the TableSection title area is:

```
<TableSection.Title>
    ABC
</TableSection.Title>
```

Is the code that sets this available for us to look at?

Answer (score 1):

It's a platform specific thing and is not defined in Xamarin.Forms somewhere. Changing it also means you will need a custom renderer, so your best bet is to simply search for the background color of their platform specific counterparts.

For iOS this is rendered as a `UITableView` of which the default background color is `#F7F7F7` from what I can find online.

For Android its set through drawables present in the theme so I'm guessing the color differs dependant on the theme.

Comment: Steven this seems to be a different color.  I think it's the color for the bottom navigation and is only used in iOS7